# Sharing links on timeline

Tags: facebook

How do I stop people from sharing links on my timeline (but still allow them to post to my timeline?  When I try to share a link on someone else's timeline, it says that they do not allow it.  I would like to find that setting.

Comment: Can you post a message on that timeline? Cause i know about a setting where only the profile holder can post on his / her's own timeline